# SSL with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, secure-coding

I'm developing several sites that I just install certs on. Chrome (Version 42.0.2311.135 m) is reporting an error that "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthorized sources".  I don't get any error in IE or FireFox.

[Page I'm seeing the error](https://www.hannibalhealth.org/AboutUs/JobsandVolunteering/Employment/tabid/126/Default.aspx)

It seems like I'm getting mixed results with (secure) embedded content since going to SSL.

Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Dave

Comment: I'm still seeing an issue with Chrome.  I'm wondering if it's actually working but it's a local caching issue, but I've deleted browser data from the beginning of time and still Chrome reports a problem on the page.  The page SSL works but the embedded content is blank?

Comment: The embedded content in the body doesn't show up on Chrome for Android either?